# Unable to show data of nested JSON file/model

Tags: json, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I've currently got a local JSON file which holds the data for numerous properties. The idea is to load this JSON file into my app, and display it into a list with options to sort it (aka rearrange the data).

Here's my **property.model.ts**

```
export class Property {
    ID: number;
    description: string;
    price: string;
    agreementType: string;
    streetName: string;
    houseNumber: number;
    postCode: string;
    place: string;
    image: Image[];
    status: string;
    constructionYear: number;
    areaSize: number;
    numberOfRooms: number;
    numberOfBedrooms: number;
    garageType: string;
    garageCapacity: number;
}

export class Image {
    ID: number;
    base64: string;
}
```

This is what my json file looks like:

```
[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "description": "Lorem ipsum...",
    "price": "€800,25",
    "agreementType": "unknown",
    "streetName": "street",
    "houseNumber": 55,
    "postCode": "postCode",
    "place": "place",
    "image": [
      {
        "ID": 1,
        "base64": ""
      },
      {
        "ID": 2,
        "base64": ""
      },
      {
        "ID": 3,
        "base64": ""
      }
    ],
    "status": "status",
    "constructionYear": 1999,
    "areaSize": 50,
    "numberOfRooms": 5,
    "numberOfBedrooms": 2,
    "garageType": "",
    "garageCapacity": 0
  },
  {
    //...
  }
]
```

and here is my **property.service.ts**

```
export class PropertyService {
    public propertyData: Observable<Property>;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {    
        this.propertyData = this.observableJson();
    }

    observableJson() : Observable<Property> {
        return this.http.get('/data/property.json')
            .map((res:Response) => { res.json(); console.log(res.json())})
            .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
    }
}
```

Later on, I want to be able to use my service elsewhere within the app as well, to (for instance) add a property object to it or something. Though I don't know if this is possible like that. But for now I just want to be able to somehow have my obserable array be useable in the property component. Which, at the moment, doesn't seem to work because when I use `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.propertyData));` inside the constructor, I get the following error:

> JS: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
>   JS: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

now, a google search tells me that this is because it's a nested JSON object, but after many attempts I haven't been able to work out how to solve this.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `Observable` probably has something self-referential inside of it which results in the error you're seeing. You don't want to `JSON.stringify` `propertyData` which is an Observable, but you want to stringify the emitted JSON response. There are a lot of different ways to do this and it depends on the circumstances of where you are using it. For example:

```
this.propertyData.subscribe(data => JSON.stringify(data));
const data = JSON.stringify(await this.propertyData.toPromise());
```

Comment: at the risk of sounding stupid - where and how would you apply this? I am quite new to Nativescript and still trying to get a hang of the application logic and such. That combined with angular, it's all a lot to take in haha :). I did try to log the first line of code, which returns [object object]... which I do not understand because you're turning it into a string, no?

Comment: `[object Object]` is a string representation of most objects. You would most likely do this in Component code, something like `ngOnInit { this.propertyData.subscribe(data => this.data = data);`. You can also use the `async` pipe in templates to get data out of observables. You probably don't need to use `JSON.stringify` at all.

Comment: Ahh I see, thanks - I will look into this. Haven't thought about using async at all for this. At least now I've got something to try :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
this.observableJson().subscribe(res => {
 this.propertyData = res;
 console.log(JSON.stringify(this.propertyData));
});
```

Comment: The output for this is "undefined".

Comment: it's because you are Logging this in your constructor, but at that time your http call is pending.

Comment: for only logging values, you can try like updated code. but to use this data outside of this method you can use 'closures'.